# SoapUI SSLException

Tags: java, ssl, jvm, soapui

So I wanted to test things through https. The problem is I'm getting this:

> Error getting response; javax.net.ssl.SSLException Received Fatal alert: illegal_parameter

I did some research in the web and I found that I should add to my vmoptions file this line:

```
-Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true
```

so I did this. But it didn't help, still getting the same error msg.

My SoapUI version is 5.0.0. Have anyone had same problem? Any tips how to solve?

Comment: Possibly similar: [SSLException: Received fatal alert: illegal_parameter after Java 1.7 upgrade](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537794/sslexception-received-fatal-alert-illegal-parameter-after-java-1-7-upgrade).

Comment: Well, I saw this topic but I got scared away by 'Tomcat' term. Anyways I used that solution and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding those 3 lines to my *.vmoptions file resolved the problem:

```
-Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true
-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.enableECC=false
-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting below option to jvm param helped me.

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dsoapui.https.protocols=TLSv1,SSLv3
```

https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-NG/ReadyAPI-1-6-and-TestRunner-quot-javax-net-ssl-SSLException/td-p/114532

Answer (score 1):

newer versions of SoapUI don't have this issue. When I upgraded to 5.4.0 this issue disappeared.