# Need clarification regarding SSL illegal_parameter alert

Tags: java, ssl

I've recently upgraded to Java 1.7 and started getting SSLException: illegal_parameter alert. However, I've come to this post ([SSLException: Received fatal alert: illegal_parameter after Java 1.7 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537794/sslexception-received-fatal-alert-illegal-parameter-after-java-1-7-upgrade)) which states a problem exactly like mine and the solution also works like a charm. But I want to understand why disabling ECC and SNI worked (I didn't have to install JCE jars only those VM args did the job)? What is the catch here? It'll be really helpful if someone could walk me through what was going wrong or at least provide some resource for me to study to understand how SSL in Java works under the hood so that I can understand the problem in details. The stacktrace provided in this problem is similar to mine so I'm not posting those here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html is the reference how "SSL in Java" (named JSSE) works for v7, assuming you are using the Oracle JRE and the Oracle providers; if you have a different JRE or customized providers you'll have to find doc for them. But this doesn't fully describe the SSL/TLS protocols since those are standardized, it focuses mostly on how JSSE fits into the Java crypto architecture (JCA) and the Java I/O model (especially the complicated but here irrelevant NIO/engine scheme). ...

Comment: ... Both ECC crypto and SNI add extensions in ClientHello that were not present previously. Both SSL and TLS were specified so that a server *should* gracefully ignore extensions it does not implement, but some servers fail(ed) to do this correctly. Only the doc or (often) error logs for the particular server you are using can tell in which exact way it fails to handle the information Java/JSSE sends, although you can experiment with various combinations to look for patterns. If this is a public server, the automated and pretty thorough test at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ may be helpful.